# Overtreatment of vintage rubber parts with Wintergreen oil

Tags: solvents, rubber

I have read in many places that treating old rubber parts with wintergreen (methyl salicylate) will soften the rubber again. The method I chose was on [this website](https://motofaction.org/mechanical-101/how-renew-soften-rubber-parts-with-oil-wintergreen-methyl-salicylate-gasket-o-rings-seals/) . I have seen many ways to do the same thing, this one appeared to appeal to me, but I wish it had not. This method using heat, was one that kept the items being treated to only 4 to 6 minutes. Other methods were much longer.

Long and short of it, I followed the instructions and ended up swelling 3 rubber parts beyond use as they are now. 2 of them can be found online, so I am only concerned about 1 part that appears to only one left in existence, the current owner must know that because they are asking top dollar for it.

The question is, is there a solvent, fluid, compound, etc. etc., that will draw out what the methyl salicylate added to the rubber to make it pliable and swell so bad?

[image]

The parts in the picture are what was affected, the 2 that are not circled still have some firmness in their handling. The one circled, the one I cannot easily replace is supposed to fit into the ring on the right side of the circle. It is a push button on my 1973 Yamaha motorcycle. The rubber as gotten very soft compared to the other items, although the camera angle does not show it well, it is still reminiscent of the "derby hat" shape it needs to fit inside the metal ring that is its retainer.

Comment: Likely, the rubber is no longer as completely polymerized as before, and nothing can be done to salvage the parts. That said, the little "cap" part seems easy to fabricate from bicycle inner tube (it looks like a primer button for a carburetor), if you're not trying to restore an antique to appear as if it had OEM parts.

Comment: The part is now really super squishy, I know it is not a chemistry term, and its shape is not  very flat that could be made of an inner tube. On the inside, there is a shape, a protrusion,  in the center that keeps a spring in place to keep the switch button (the rubber piece in question) from grounding out on its own since it is a kill switch for my classic dirt bike.

Comment: I had a conversation with another rider that seemed very knowledgeable about things, at least about my plastic screw in gas cap that is for the same bike. It told him how it shrunk and the threads that tightened the cap in place would not engage anymore onto the tank. I had to get a new cap to replace the original. He explained to me that the hydrocarbons in the gas in the tank affected the hydrocarbons in the cap and the cap shrunk from the exposure. Or something like that. I was hoping that I could dunk the part in something that might do the same thing that happened to the original gas cap.

Comment: While I never rode a motor bike, I wonder why replacing the broken/outworn piece with a new one doesn't restore *the function*. By a brief search, suppliers like [sumorubber](https://sumorubber.com/miscellaneous?limit=100), or [Yahama parts house](https://www.yamahapartshouse.com/oemparts/c/yamaha_motorcycle/parts). Or, if there were communities to exchange *elder, yet still functional* spare pieces made *back then*, similar to [brick link](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) occasionally mentioned on bricks.se. Or maybe a visit at  [mechanics.se](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Its simply a matter of keeping the originality of the bike, no more. The more original the bike the better. Some parts do wear out, like tires and drive chain. When those parts get replaced it is an accepted norm. A kill button/stop switch in my case, receives no real wear to speak of, so to keep it intact is desirable. But in all it is vanity.... And when all is said and done I may need to install a reproduction of the item. I have through another forum, they are available for a more reasonable price than the first one I found. But I need to try all avenues to restore this part if possible.